# React component for adding skills is not working on IOS but working fine on android in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

React component in my app which is just like `TextInput` which takes input from users and gives auto-complete suggestions like if I try to write `node` then it will give suggestions dropdown with `node.js`. This react component is working fine on android but on the ios simulator, it's not working. I am not able to open the keyboard.

On the android simulator, everything is working fine.

```
 <SearchableDropdown
                            onTextChange={async (text) => {
                              console.log("text is", text);
                              await this.loadSearchData(text);
                              if (text) {
                                this.setState({
                                  search: true,
                                });
                              } else {
                                this.setState({
                                  search: false,
                                });
                              }
                            }}
                            check={(text) => {
                              if (text == true && !this.state.search) {
                                this.setState({
                                  search: true,
                                });
                              }
                            }}
                            //On text change listner on the searchable input
                            onItemSelect={(item) => {
                              console.log("selected", item.name);
                              let skills = this.state.skills;
                              if (!skills.find((skill) => skill == item.name)) {
                                skills.push(item.name);
                              }
                              console.log("Selected skills are", skills);
                              this.setState({
                                skills: skills,
                              });
                            }}
                            //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
                            containerStyle={{ padding: 0 }}
                            //suggestion container style
                            textInputStyle={{
                              //inserted text style

                              width: wp("82%"),
                              padding: 8,
                              // marginTop: hp('1.67%'),

                              borderColor: this.state.search ? "#fff" : "#fff",
                              backgroundColor: this.state.search
                                ? "#fff"
                                : "#fff",
                              borderRadius: 6,
                            }}
                            itemStyle={{
                              //single dropdown item style

                              padding: 10,
                              //marginTop: 2,
                              backgroundColor: this.state.search
                                ? "#fff"
                                : "#FAF9F8",
                              // borderColor: '#bbb',
                              // borderWidth: 1,
                              width: "100%",
                            }}
                            itemTextStyle={{
                              //single dropdown item's text style
                              color: "#222",
                            }}
                            itemsContainerStyle={{
                              //items container style you can pass maxHeight
                              //to restrict the items dropdown hieght
                              opacity: 1,
                              zIndex: 999,
                              position: "absolute",
                              width: wp("91.7%"),
                              marginTop: hp("7%"),
                              //height: 100,
                              // maxHeight: '60%',
                              borderRadius: 6,
                              borderWidth: 1,
                              borderColor: "#BFBEBE",
                              backgroundColor: "white",
                            }}
                            listProps={{
                              nestedScrollEnabled: true,
                            }}
                            items={this.state.skillData}
                            //mapping of item array

                            //default selected item index
                            placeholder={"e.g., Node.js, Python, React..."}
                            placeholderTextColor={"#BFBEBE"}
                            //place holder for the search input
                            resetValue={false}
                            //reset textInput Value with true and false state
                            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                            //To remove the underline from the android input
                          />
```

Below is my parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { search, trend } from "../../assets/index";

const defaultItemValue = {
  name: "",
  id: 0,
};

export default class SearchableDropDown extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTextInput = this.renderTextInput.bind(this);
    this.renderFlatList = this.renderFlatList.bind(this);
    this.searchedItems = this.searchedItems.bind(this);
    this.renderItems = this.renderItems.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      item: {},
      listItems: [],
      focus: false,
    };
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      this._keyboardDidShow
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      this._keyboardDidHide
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    //alert('Keyboard Shown');
    // console.log(this.state.focus, 'dd');
    this.setState({
      focus: true,
    });
  };

  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    //alert('Keyboard Hidden');
    this.setState({
      focus: false,
      item: defaultItemValue,
    });
    //console.log(this.state);
  };

  renderFlatList = () => {
    if (this.state.focus) {
      const flatListPorps = { ...this.props.listProps };
      const oldSupport = [
        {
          key: "check",
          val: (text) => {
            this.state.focus;
          },
        },
        { key: "keyboardShouldPersistTaps", val: "always" },
        { key: "nestedScrollEnabled", val: false },
        { key: "style", val: { ...this.props.itemsContainerStyle } },
        { key: "data", val: this.props.items },
        { key: "keyExtractor", val: (item, index) => String(item.id) },
        {
          key: "renderItem",
          val: ({ item, index }) => this.renderItems(item, index),
        },
      ];
      oldSupport.forEach((kv) => {
        if (!Object.keys(flatListPorps).includes(kv.key)) {
          flatListPorps[kv.key] = kv.val;
        } else {
          if (kv.key === "style") {
            flatListPorps["style"] = kv.val;
          }
        }
      });
      const check = this.props.check;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (typeof check === "function") check(this.state.focus);
      });
      return <FlatList {...flatListPorps} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" />;
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const listItems = this.props.items;
    const defaultIndex = this.props.defaultIndex;
    // if (defaultIndex && listItems.length > defaultIndex) {
    //     this.setState({
    //         listItems,
    //         item: listItems[defaultIndex]
    //     });
    // } else {
    this.setState({ listItems });
    // }
  };

  searchedItems = (searchedText) => {
    let setSort = this.props.setSort;
    if (!setSort && typeof setSort !== "function") {
      setSort = (item, searchedText) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchedText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      };
    }
    var ac = this.props.items.filter((item) => {
      return setSort(item, searchedText);
    });
    let item = {
      id: -1,
      name: searchedText,
    };
    this.setState({ listItems: ac, item: item });
    const onTextChange =
      this.props.onTextChange ||
      this.props.textInputProps.onTextChange ||
      this.props.onChangeText ||
      this.props.textInputProps.onChangeText;
    if (onTextChange && typeof onTextChange === "function") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        onTextChange(searchedText);
      }, 0);
    }
    // const check = this.props.check;
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   if (typeof check === 'function')
    //     check(this.state.focus);
    // })
  };

  renderItems = (item, index) => {
    if (
      this.props.multi &&
      this.props.selectedItems &&
      this.props.selectedItems.length > 3
    ) {
      return this.props.selectedItems.find((sitem) => sitem.id === item.id) ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ ...this.props.itemStyle, flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 0.9,
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "flex-start",
            }}
          >
            <Image style={styles.logo} source={trend} />
            {/*  */}
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{ flex: 0.1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-end" }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.props.onRemoveItem(item, index);
                }, 0)
              }
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#f16d6b",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
                borderRadius: 100,
                marginLeft: 10,
              }}
            >
              <Text>X</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ item: item });
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.props.onItemSelect(item);
            }, 0);
          }}
          style={{ ...this.props.itemStyle, flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}
        >
          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-start" }}
          >
            <Image style={{ margin: 2 }} source={trend} />
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.7}
          onLongPress={() => console.log("Long pressed")}
          style={{ ...this.props.itemStyle }}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("Item is", item);
            this.setState({ item: item, focus: false });
            // this.props.onItemSelect(item);
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.props.onItemSelect(item);
              if (this.props.resetValue) {
                this.setState({ focus: true, item: defaultItemValue });
                this.input.focus();
              }
            }, 0);
          }}
        >
          {this.props.selectedItems &&
          this.props.selectedItems.length > 3 &&
          this.props.selectedItems.find((x) => x.id === item.id) ? null : (
            <Image style={{ margin: 2 }} source={trend} />
          )}
          <Text style={{ ...this.props.itemTextStyle }}>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  };

  renderListType = () => {
    return this.renderFlatList();
  };

  renderTextInput = () => {
    const textInputProps = { ...this.props.textInputProps };
    const oldSupport = [
      {
        key: "check",
        val: (text) => {
          this.state.focus;
        },
      },
      { key: "ref", val: (e) => (this.input = e) },
      {
        key: "onTextChange",
        val: (text) => {
          this.searchedItems(text);
        },
      },
      { key: "underlineColorAndroid", val: this.props.underlineColorAndroid },
      {
        key: "onFocus",
        val: () => {
          this.props.onFocus && this.props.onFocus();
          this.setState({
            focus: true,
            item: defaultItemValue,
            listItems: this.props.items,
          });
        },
      },
      {
        key: "onBlur",
        val: () => {
          this.props.onBlur && this.props.onBlur();
          this.setState({ focus: false });
        },
      },
      {
        key: "value",
        val: this.state.item.name,
      },
      {
        key: "style",
        val: { ...this.props.textInputStyle },
      },
      {
        key: "placeholderTextColor",
        val: this.props.placeholderTextColor,
      },
      {
        key: "placeholder",
        val: this.props.placeholder,
      },
    ];
    oldSupport.forEach((kv) => {
      if (!Object.keys(textInputProps).includes(kv.key)) {
        if (kv.key === "onTextChange" || kv.key === "onChangeText") {
          textInputProps["onChangeText"] = kv.val;
        } else {
          textInputProps[kv.key] = kv.val;
        }
      } else {
        if (kv.key === "onTextChange" || kv.key === "onChangeText") {
          textInputProps["onChangeText"] = kv.val;
        }
      }
    });
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 6,
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: this.state.focus ? "#fff" : "#fff",
          borderRadius: 6,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#BFBEBE",
        }}
      >
        <TextInput pointerEvents="none" onKeyPress={null} {...textInputProps} />
        <Image
          style={{
            marginRight: 10,
          }}
          source={search}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View
        // keyboardShouldPersist="always"
        style={{ ...this.props.containerStyle }}
      >
        {this.renderSelectedItems()}
        {this.renderTextInput()}
        {this.renderListType()}
      </View>
    );
  };
  renderSelectedItems() {
    let items = this.props.selectedItems;
    if (
      items !== undefined &&
      items.length > 3 &&
      this.props.chip &&
      this.props.multi
    ) {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            paddingBottom: 10,
            marginTop: 5,
          }}
        >
          {items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <View
                key={index}
                style={{
                  width: item.name.length * 8 + 60,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  flex: 0,
                  backgroundColor: "#eee",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  margin: 5,
                  padding: 8,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                }}
              >
                <Text style={{ color: "#555" }}>{item.name}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() =>
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      this.props.onRemoveItem(item, index);
                    }, 0)
                  }
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#f16d6b",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    width: 25,
                    height: 25,
                    borderRadius: 100,
                    marginLeft: 10,
                  }}
                >
                  <Text>X</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why it is not working on my ios simulator. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try installing the pods again and check. cd ios && pod install

Comment: Already tried this.